# AutoTab to Next TabPage in TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

C# .Net fw 3.5, in winform in TabControl, 
when the user tab out of the last control on a TabPage, then focus should moves to the next page, and focuses the first control in that page, how can i do it?

this is necessary for me because, in a master entry form, there is some compulsory questions which is placed out side of tabcontrol, and some controls which is not necessary all in tabcontrol,

if user visiting each control sequentially then focus should automatically move to next pages, if user want to fill only neccessory infos, then he can submit by clicking save button.

is any suggestion about this.

Comment: This is very hard to do by overriding the Tab key behavior in a generic way.  A silly trick works: add a button with a size of (0, 0).  In its Enter event set the focus to the next control you want selected.

Answer (score 1):

your question is not accurate
 "C# .Net fw 3.5, in winform in TabControl, when the user tab out of the last control on a TabPage, then focus should moves to the next page, and focuses the first control in that page?"

is this a statement or question. I didnt understand. And what is the goal you need ?
If you want the user consequently visit the controls inside the consequent tabs by pressing tab key you can do it by keypressed event in tab control. In the keypressed event you can change the tab programatically.
hope it helps.

The code should be something like this.
Generate keypress event for your tabcontrol and monitor the press of TAB key.

```
    private void tabControl1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ToString().Equals("TAB") // I dont know what tab key returns. But is hould be something like this
        {
              tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[1] ;
              // now tabpage 2 has the focus
              // You can also focus any control you want in here as follows:
              tabControl1.TabPages[1].Control["control key"].Focus();
        }
    }
```

hope its clear enough

Comment: when tab key pressed on last control in a tabpage then focus moved to then next control of the tabcontrol, my tabindexes are set well, and cursor doesn't focus to next tabpage.

if you have any solution then please provide and please describe briefly.

Comment: whats is the result you want ?

Comment: i have a tabcontrol in which three tabpages exists, when user press tab key on last contrl of tabpage then next first control of next tabpage should be focused.

Comment: I have edited my answer please have a look at the code sample. its incomplete but it should give you the basic idea.Tell us the result after you try please

Comment: your code is incomplete i have developed i my own control have a look

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CSBSSWControls
{
    // Class inhertis TabControl
    public class bssTabControl : TabControl
    {
        private bool AutoTab_;
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool AutoTab { get { return AutoTab_; } set { AutoTab_ = value; } }
        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            //property which determines auto change tabpages
            if (AutoTab)
            {
                switch (keyData)
                {
                    case Keys.Tab | Keys.Shift:
                        {
                            return SetNextTab(false);
                        }
                    case Keys.Tab:
                        {
                            return SetNextTab(true);
                        }
                }
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
        private bool SetNextTab(bool Forward)
        {
            // getting cuurent active control
            ContainerControl CC = this.FindForm();
            Control ActC = null;
            while (CC != null)
            {
                ActC = CC.ActiveControl;
                CC = ActC as ContainerControl;
            }
            //checking, current control should not be tabcontrol or tabpage
            if (ActC != null && !(ActC is TabPage) && !(ActC is bssTabControl))
            {
                //getting current controls next control if it is tab page then current control is surely that last control on that tab page
                //if shift+tab pressed then checked its previous control, if it is tab page then current control is first control on the current tab page.
                TabPage NC = ActC.FindForm().GetNextControl(ActC, Forward) as TabPage;
                if (NC != null)
                    if (this.TabPages.Contains(NC))
                        if (Forward)
                        {
                            //selecting next tab page
                            this.SelectedTab = NC;
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (this.TabPages.IndexOf(NC) > 0)
                            {
                                //selecting pervious tab page
                                this.SelectedIndex = this.TabPages.IndexOf(NC) - 1;
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```